# Get word #n in javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, words

How would I get word # n in a string with javascript. I.e. if I want to get word #3 in "Pumpkin pie and ice cream", I want "and" returned. Is there some little function to do this, or could someone write one? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the string on the " " character and then return the nth-1 element of the array (this example doesn't include any bounds checking so be careful):

```
var getNthWord = function(string, n){
    var words = string.split(" ");
    return words[n-1];
}
```

Comment: how would I get the last word?

Comment: Better yet, [string.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: @Leticia Meyer - instead of returning words[n-1] you would return words[words.length - 1]. I'm starting to wonder though...is this homework?

Comment: @Justin Simpler: `function(s, n) { return s.split(' ')[--n]; };`

Comment: @Brad - Passing no separator in JavaScript will result in a single element in the array that contains the original string rather than splitting on whitespace.

Comment: @Šime - While that may be more compact, it would be more difficult to a beginner to understand...which is why I broke it up.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: That was more so a comment redirecting to the MDN (Mozilla version of docs) instead of w3schools, not a comment on implementation.

Comment: @Brad - Doh! Sorry. Updated. I'm still trying to kick the W3Schools habit for stuff like this.

Comment: @Justin If the OP doesn't understand the code, you can append an explanation. The idea is to provide the best possible solution.

Comment: @Šime: I don't think a one liner is better than the clear two liner! Also, there is no reason for you to decrement n, since you're not using it after the statement. Justin's function is very clear, while yours is more Perl like :) @Justin: how about split on a Regex /\s/, or even better, as mentioned by Justin Thomas, /\W/ ?

Comment: @Justin, no this is not homework. I'm just learning javascript, and this problem came up.

Comment: @Leticia - No problem...just checking.

Comment: @Juan I'm decrementing `n` because arrays are zero-based, so for the 3-rd word `n` has to be 2, etc.

Comment: @Šime: I understand that, it's just that you're never using the value of n after that statement, so in my mind, it makes more sense to just call `words[n-1]` instead of `words[--n]`

Comment: @Juan `words[n-1]` and `words[--n]` are equivalent. They both decrement `n` and then look up the corresponding item in the array. I don't know what you mean...

Comment: @Šime: They are not equivalent, the value of n is changed, it's an unwanted side effect since n stands for the number of the word to be fetched, so it doesn't make semantic sense to decrement the variable. What you call simpler, is shorter, but not simpler.

Comment: @Juan You're right. `--n` is equivalent to `n=n-1` but not to `n-1`. `words[n-1]` is better.

Comment: Its a bit weak. Multiple spaces concatenated produce empty strings. You are ignoring linebreaks or nbsps, etc. You have to either: a) clean the string with a regex. or b) iterate over words ignoring empty strings and pray not to find out a linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can split your string based on space, get the array and then look for value from the index n-1.

```
var myStr = "Pumpkin pie and ice cream";
var strArr = myStr.split(String.fromCharCode(32)) //ascii code for space is 32.

var requiredWord = strArr[n-1];
var firstWord = strArr[0];
var lastWord = strArr[ strArr.length - 1 ];
```

Ofcourse error handling is left to you.

Comment: Example please? I'm a noob at javascript.

Comment: Also, how would I get the first and last word?

Comment: @LeticiaMeyer: `alert("Pumkin pie and ice cream".split(' ')[2]);` && `var s = "Pumpkin pie and ice cream".split(' '); alert(s[0]+','+s[s.length-1]);`

Comment: @Leticia Meyer - Edited to get your first and last word too

Answer (score 0):

Use the split function to get the individual words into a list, then just grab the word that's in index n - 1.

```
var sentence = "Pumpkin pie and ice cream";
var words[] = sentence.split(" ");
print words[2]; // if you want word 3, since indexes go from 0 to n-1, rather than 1 to n.
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be:

```
var str = "Pumpkin pie and ice cream"; //your string
var word = 3; //word number
var word = str.split(" ")[word - 1];
```

However, this does not take consideration of other whitespace(tabs, newlines...) or periods and commas.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the non-word based split: "test,test2 test3".split(/\W/) would yield: [test,test2,test3].

Comment: Yes but `'foo, bar'` would yield `['foo', '', 'bar']`